# Change element's innertext with php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, echo

I want to change a innerText of a element using php (I also use jquery); and I've tried this:

```
<?php
    $variable = "Hello";
    echo '<script>$('#element').text($variable);</script>'
?>
```

But it didn't work. I've also tried with:

```
document.getElementsById('element').innerText = $variable;
```

Comment: With jQuery `echo "<script>$('#element').text('" . $variable . "');</script>"` or pure JS `echo "document.getElementsById('element').innerText = '" . $variable . "';"`

Comment: Do you have the jQuery library included on this page

Comment: Also check that you are able to use $ instead of jQuery when calling for jQuery actions and functions.

Comment: Or use \ to escape strings

Comment: the result of script is this: `<script>$('#resultat').text('a b c d');</script>`, and it says undetermined string literal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a quotes problem as @Robiseb mentioned in the **[above comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40091944/change-elements-innertext-with-php/40092063#comment-67456562)**, use :

```
echo "<script>$('#element').text('" . $variable . "');</script>"
//Or
echo "document.getElementsById('element').textContent = '" . $variable . "';"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The console of the browser says:

Comment: `SyntaxError: unterminated string literal`

Comment: thanks, I revised my code and between the a and the b there was a line, now it works

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
 document.getElementById('element').innerHTML = $variable;
```

or

```
$('#element').html($variable);
```